# How to scroll text on an OLED display using only the SSD1306Wire library?

Tags: esp8266, display, oled

I'm a 13 years old boy and I am doing a project with esp01 and an OLED screen to display project ideas on the OLED with the ChatGPT API. The answer is displayed on the OLED but I would like it to scroll from bottom to top and so on to the next query so I can see the whole answer.I noted that the only library that worked for me for the esp01 was the SSD1306Wire library .My code is :

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SSD1306Wire.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h> 

const char* ssid = "WIFI_NAME";
const char* password = "WIFI_PASSWORD";

const char* apiEndpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-002/completions";
const char* apiToken = "OPENAI_TOKEN";

SSD1306Wire  display(0x3c, 2, 0);  
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
 
 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
   delay(1000);
   Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
 }

 Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

 display.init();
 display.flipScreenVertically();
 display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_10);
}

void loop() {
 WiFiClientSecure client;
 client.setInsecure();
 HTTPClient http;
 http.begin(client, apiEndpoint);
 http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 http.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + String(apiToken));
 String payload = "{\"prompt\": \"TEXT_TO_QUERY\",\"temperature\":0.8,\"max_tokens\":40}";
 int httpResponseCode = http.POST(payload);
 String response = "";

 if (httpResponseCode == 200) {
   response = http.getString();
   int startIndex = response.indexOf("text\":") + 7;
   int endIndex = response.indexOf("\",\"index\"");
   response = response.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
   response.replace("\\n", "\n");
   Serial.println(response);
 } else {
   Serial.print("Error: ");
   Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
 }

 http.end();


 display.clear();
 display.drawStringMaxWidth(0, 0, 128, response);
 display.display();

 delay(18000000);  
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: have you looked at the example sketches?

Comment: The 5 hour pause is supposed to be 30 minutes, my mistake. The library doesn't seem to have example sketches.

Comment: then do an internet search for `SSD1306Wire.h`

Comment: But my problem is that the library does not support the scroll function

Comment: Are  you asking for smooth scrolling or jumping by a character or line of text?  Assuming the former, are you asking for horizontal scrolling or vertical scrolling.  I think horizontal scrolling is supported but is undocumented.  I'm not sure about vertical scrolling.

Comment: I would like the texte to scroll smoothly
From the bottom to the top

Comment: The library I think you are using is hosted at github.com and does not appear to support vertical scrolling as there has been discussion that looks to have ended about vertical scrolling in the issues.  It may support horizontal scrolling, but that discussion also points to a fork of the project on another github.com page. If you want to know more I suggest going there and reading these discussions.  Perhaps participating in them.

Comment: Ok thank you . Should I close the discussion or something like that?

Comment: You, or the person answering your question (@st2000) should convert the comments into an actual answer. Then it can be marked as accepted, in order to help others with the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The SSD1306Wire code, its development history and discussions can be [found here on github.com](https://github.com/ThingPulse/esp8266-oled-ssd1306).
- The Google search pattern "scroll
  site:github.com/ThingPulse/esp8266-oled-ssd1306" can be used to find
  all matches to "scroll" on these web pages. There appears to be
  interest in vertical scrolling by others but no support as of yet.
  There also appears to be some horizontal scrolling support or success as
  discussed [in this github.com issue for this project](https://github.com/ThingPulse/esp8266-oled-ssd1306/issues/160).
- Also in that thread, there is [a link to another DSS1306 github.com project
  which explicitly states it supports horizontal scrolling](https://github.com/androdlang/InfoTicker).